# Batch check if a folder has only .jpg or .png files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, findstr

Currently I have a part of a script which checks a specific folder for whether it is empty or not.

```
dir /A /B "C:\Users\tpscreen\Desktop\Bilder Pausenraum" | findstr /L ".">NUL && GOTO NotEmpty
```

However, I would much rather check if the folder has only .jpg and .png files in it. Any clues how I can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You are already using `findstr`, just manipulate it to look something like: `findstr /i "\.jpg \.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution.

findstr /L /V ".jpg .png"

/V Inverts the answer. So it shows every File which isn't a .jpg or .png